# What is purpose of `unwrap()` if the return value is not used?

Tags: error-handling, rust, stdin

I found this Rust code for getting a line from `stdin`:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
    println!("Input: {}", line);
}
```

`io::stdin().read_line(&mut line)` sets the `line` variable to a line read from `stdin`. From my understanding, `read_line()` returns a `Result` value, which can be pattern-matched, or `.unwrap()` can be used to get the inner value if it is not an `Err`.

However, the returned value of `read_line()` is never used. Only the `line` string variable is used, but people use `.unwrap()` most of the time even if it is not used.

What is the purpose of `unwrap()` if the returned value is not used? Just to throw an error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the purpose of `unwrap()` if the returned value is not used? Just to throw an error?

**Yes, but that's not all**.

Ignoring potential errors is bad; there's a big difference between an empty `line` and a `line` that's not been read because of an error; for example in a typical "pipeline" command in a shell, the program *needs* to stop when it stops receiving input, otherwise the user has to kill it.

In C, ignoring errors is too easy. Many languages solve this by having exceptions, but Rust doesn't.

In order to avoid the issue plaguing C programs that it's too easy to forget to check the return code, normally Rust functions will bundle the expected return value and error in `Result`, so that you *have* to check it to get the return value.

There is one potential issue left, however: what if the caller doesn't care about the return value? Most notably, when the value is `()`, nobody really cares about it.

There is a bit of compiler magic invoked here: the `Result` structure is tagged with the `#[must_use]` attribute. This attribute makes it **mandatory to do something with `Result`** when it's returned.

Therefore, in your case, not only is unwrapping good, it's also the simplest way to "do something" and avoid a compilation warning.

Comment: *a bit of compiler magic* — it's not restricted to the compiler, FWIW. Any user type can also be annotated with `#[must_use]`.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Sure, the attribute itself however *is* magic (black magic, I would argue). I mean, it could be modeled "properly" in the type system if Rust supported Linear Types (instead of merely Affine Types), however it doesn't and instead we have this little attribute which makes a type "close-to-linear-but-not-quite".

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to "elegantly" handle cases where there is a failure to read a line from stdin (e.g. by attempting it once again or picking a default value), you can use `unwrap()` to trigger a panic; it silences the warning caused by a `Result` that is not used:

```
warning: unused result which must be used
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     io::stdin().read_line(&mut line);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
```